# Conditional terms in Python list initialization

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension, nonetype

I want to do something like this:

```
a = some_funct()
b = [ 1, a if a is not None ]
```

The list b should be one element long if a is None, and two elements long if a is not None.  Is this possible in Python or do I have to use a separate if check followed by add()?

Comment: How about `b = [1]; if a is not None: b.append(a)`?

Comment: Alternatively, `b = [x for x in (1, a) if x is not None]` ... but check-then-append is going to be more readable.

Comment: b=[1];a and b.append(a)    ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look the best, but you could do

```
b = [1] + ([a] if a is not None else [])
```

Of course, it would be better to check as it increases code readability.

Comment: I like this because it does not call list.append and supports lists which contain any value, including None.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using list comprehension

```
b = [x for x in (1, a) if x is not None]
```

The tuple `(1, a)` is the total set, b will become a list of all elements in that total set which are not `None`

Answer (score 3):

```
a = some_funct()
b = [ 1, a ] if a is not None else [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm way too late to this game, but I had the same question and after seeing other answers, I came up with this solution using `sets`:

```
list({1, a or 1})
```

Comment: Clever solution for initializing lists of max two items.